# Why Does Combining Cases in Rust's match Statement Cause Multiple Mutable Borrow Errors?

Tags: rust

I'm working on LeetCode problem 203 "[Remove Linked List Elements](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-linked-list-elements/)" in Rust and ran into an interesting issue involving `match` statements. Specifically, combining two cases into one in a `match` statement leads to a compilation error, while keeping them separate works fine.

Here's the version that **doesn't compile**:

```rust
pub fn remove_elements(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>, val: i32) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    let mut head = head;
    let mut walker = &mut head;

    loop {
        match walker {
            Some(node) => {
                if node.val != val {
                    *walker = node.next.take();
                } else {
                    walker = &mut node.next;
                }
            }
            _ => break,
        }
    }
    head
}
```

The compiler error messages are:

```
Line 23, Char 19: cannot use `*walker` because it was mutably borrowed (solution.rs)
   |
23 |             match walker {
   |                   ^^^^^^
   |                   |
   |                   use of borrowed `walker.0`
   |                   borrow later used here
24 |                 Some(node) => {
   |                      ---- borrow of `walker.0` occurs here
Line 24, Char 22: cannot borrow `walker.0` as mutable more than once at a time (solution.rs)
   |
24 |                 Some(node) => {
   |                      ^^^^ `walker.0` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
Line 26, Char 25: cannot assign to `*walker` because it is borrowed (solution.rs)
   |
24 |                 Some(node) => {
   |                      ---- borrow of `*walker` occurs here
25 |                     if node.val != val {
26 |                         *walker = node.next.take();
   |                         ^^^^^^^
   |                         |
   |                         assignment to borrowed `*walker` occurs here
   |                         borrow later used here
Some errors have detailed explanations: E0499, E0503, E0506.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
error: could not compile `prog` due to 3 previous errors
mv: cannot stat '/leetcode/rust_compile/target/release/prog': No such file or directory
```

On the other hand, when I separate the cases, the code compiles without issue:

```rust
pub fn remove_elements(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>, val: i32) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    let mut head = head;
    let mut walker = &mut head;

    loop {
        match walker {
            Some(node) if node.val != val => walker = &mut node.next,
            Some(node) => *walker = node.next.take(),
            _ => break,
        }
    }
    head
}
```

I'd like to understand why separating the conditions into different cases resolves the mutable borrow error. Could anyone shed light on this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

It's a limitation of the current borrow checker. Polonius [will fix it](https://rust.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYgATKVpMGoYgFcFBUkvrICeAZUboAwqlpmWDfaWcAZPAZMADlPACNMYn0AZlIAB1QFQgcGNw8vHwSk%2BwEAoNCWCKi9WJtMOxShAiZiAjTPbwMyioEqmoI8kPDImOtq2vqMpv6OwK7CnpKASmtUM2Jkdg4AUhLlgFYAISxiPAA3TAhldrwxbABHUgBqC%2BuXWgFMa4ARTDCzYCmN5%2BWNAEE4mYwldLOY7FcApZghhMFdlgB2Ta/P5XVFXQHAvZiEBXPDRAzItHooFXIKqAg4gDycRyDGW0Rcm1QqnpLkhBGhWHp2G5pGRCJ%2B/wxVyoDCuxEwLFQBwA%2Bph6GxBAoIAhMEx0FSaSlWUyWQz2ZzMNzeVcsbQcXi9FMrgBablXam0nXM1kGmHG6LYOGIwlo%2BgEK4sMwB1XquHRZ5XUPoelI/5E/2B4NXADuYgA1pFw5HVgA2IMhtUx6Jxv6%2B1EPVBxb2lolElhMAjIBCpjNZhG1utdoSoNgQBgw630n6emvlrsTvBUUkwgB0ZquYDAw9NYjH8Ynm6JACo07RM8RszOsLOyQRZ9VMxAvhut3WBVd5Up1yi71u9wej3mC8fMKfMOS45vt6gqvneApAROMrZvaYQSkw6Z8re97wqBRIQch0b8qhHAzOaHDrLw3gcFopCoJwABKFgBgocwLLCqz4rwFIkbhMzRj016kOmIDRAAnLOkiSHofF8fxGjwvCkjrAAHPChicJIvAsBIGgaKQxGkeRHC8AoIDqSxWgzHAsBIGgLBxHQkTkJQ5mWfQUQMHgwAIAQtAAJ6kFgex4IsABqeCYCm1KMJwPB8HQBCRHpEBhJovBhIENTuWFCVJcQ7mUmE2jlCx4XmYqBCUgwHnxV5bwfC4Yi0Hp3C8FgDYmOIrFeXgEoVActWkQB5TBks4WBFF%2BGkbQeBwclbhYGVBC7CpdUzFQRjAAoAVBSFxHhfwggiGI7BSDIgiKCo6gtboBhGCYIDmJYhhjXpkAzFWtK1TaABaCQPE5Fi8NKkS7Fg91cc0tJOAwrjuA0Ei%2BGDnQFEUUNZMkAiDN4XDxIkSMMLD3RRGjwOVCMKNQ/jrQjNjEy4307RE3jZNjHDPRcDMtHzIs%2Bh4ZwhEaWV2nitRyCks5rkeVcEC4IQJBwiUVrMfFUzsUWnEzDxejwrOeglLm8Kq7JfF6BoMkaOdinKap6maT9nC6fppCGbhpAmYgIBzAQgJWBQEB2VZxDBKwSzXU2gsuW57m8Jg%2BBEP9PhbcIojiPtMdHWoZVnaQKbEEwcSpRzBFETznCUsGbtXKg04BwLTnByLEBuBZ3tS/iUyy6x8vcbx0SztEXfdz3PcKRwSncy12nWwZcs53oefD1btvj6QBzEEkjiSEAA%3D%3D).

Comment: Could you elaborate on what specific limitation of the current borrow checker is causing this issue? Also, how does Polonius fix this?

Comment: It cannot properly deduce the lifetimes used across if branches. By deducing more apropriate lifetimes.

Comment: So the borrow checker is not able to infer that the two borrows in the different branches are conditional and don't overlap?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it conservatively assumes both borrows last for the whole `if` expression.

Comment: I thought Rust introduced non-lexical lifetimes in 1.63? Wouldn't that fix this issue?

Comment: Does the code compile? —evidently not— so no, they don't fix the issue where a reference *could* still be in use or not.

Comment: Can I think about this another way:
1. walker = &mut node.next; enforces the borrow of walker(through node and node.next) to last at least for the scope of walker
2. *walker = node.next.take() changes the content of walker during its scope(where it is borrowed because of 1)